# Dispatch N work items to M node

Tags: azure, distributed

This problem seems to be common but I don't find any concrete discussion about it. Sorry if this has been already asked.

There are N work items stored in storage (I am using Azure table storage) and there are M worker machines that run in parallel. What I want to achieve is:

1. Dispatch work items to worker machines evenly.
2. After dispatch, before worker machine finishing process of its work items, if it's died, any other machine can pick up the work items.

So far I have 3 possible solutions in my mind.

1. Let each worker machine compete to fetch work items from Azure table storage directly.
2. Introduce a new component which is responsible for reading work items from Azure table storage and put them into some queue service (Azure Queue storage), and then each worker machine picks up from the Queue.
3. Introduce a new component which is responsible for reading work items from Azure table storage and divide them into partitions based on the number of active worker machines and expose a service API (probably restful service) to let worker machine to get partitioned work items from this new component.

I am inclined to the 3rd option, but want to know if there are any other ideas that are known to be good to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: You may want to use `Azure Batch`. I have used it in the past and it does what you are looking for.

Comment: This is a producer/consumer pattern. It is typically implemented by using queues in the middle and worker roles on the consumer side and that s what I would recommend. A few things to consider, the work items you write to the queue need to be idempotent, the ones that cannot be processed successfully after a few tries should be moved to a separate error queue and logged. You may also want to keep the status of each work item in table storage for reporting purposes etc.